# Group a number of Excel columns into rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

Currently, I am working on a column with the content for teacher's comment.

I would like to delimit it by the space or comma or punctuation marks between words inside the content.

At the same time, I would like to take out each of the words in the content and then place them into rows instead of columns .

Example:

> Catherine is a good girl . -> This is the teacher's comment.

After delimit in excel, I have "Catherine is a good girl . " in 6 columns with 1 column for 1 word.

However, I would like the outcome of the words to be placed into rows. It would look like this, in 6 rows:

```
Catherine
is
a
good
girl
.
```

Answer (score 2):

[Excel has the ability to do that](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rotate-data-by-converting-columns-to-rows-or-vice-versa-HP005203138.aspx).

> 1. Copy the data in one or more columns or rows.
> 2. Before you paste the copied data, right-click your first destination cell (the first cell of the row or column into which you want to paste your data), and then click Paste Special.
> 3. In the Paste Special dialog box, select Transpose, and then click OK.
>
> You'll find theTranspose check box in the lower-right corner of the dialog box:

[image]

The article comes from Excel 2003 help, but the process applies all the way up to the newest Excel.  The dialog box might look different though.

Comment: After putting each word into its own variable, how do I put the few rows into one column instead?

 

a     b     c

d     e     f

g     h     i

 

to

 

a

b

c

d

e

f

g

h

i

 However, this is just a sample try out. 
I am working with large data of 2000 values 
So any way of going about it ? 

Thanks

Comment: ?? You can select your entire current Excel sheet, choose copy, "insert" a new worksheet, and "paste special" - transpose all of your current work at once.  You don't have to do one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code will do the trick.

```
Sub FlattenToSingleCol()
    Cells(1, 1).Activate ' Go to the top left

    ' Go past the last row that starts with a word
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        DoEvents
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop

    ' Set curRow to the last row that starts with a word (the row above ActiveCell)
    curRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1

    Do While curRow > 0
        DoEvents
        Cells(curRow, 1).Activate

        ' Go right past the last cell that contains a word
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            DoEvents
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Loop

        ' Come back left to the last cell that contains a word
        If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
        End If

        ' Insert a new row below the current one for each
        Do Until ActiveCell.Column = 1 ' Move each non-empty cell to a new row and move left to the edge
            DoEvents
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            ActiveCell.Clear
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Loop

        ' Go to the row above. Processing from the bottom up avoids re-processing lines we just inserted below.
        curRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```