# Putting the few rows into one Excel 2007 column instead

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Is there any way of putting the few rows I have in an Excel 2007 spreadsheet into one column instead?

```
a b c 
d e f 
g h i
```

to

```
a 
b 
c 
d 
e 
f 
g 
h 
i
```

This is just a sample try out. I am working with large data set of 2000 values and want to know how I can convert the rows into a single column.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I can think of a rather involved way of doing it in excel (using indirect and offset) hoping someone else has a better way. How many rows are there?

Comment: @soandos If it is a text file, then you can use a programming language to iterate over each token (value of interest) and place them on their own line.

Comment: @iglvzx Right, but if it starts out as a non csv excel file, its harder

Comment: @cody_q, if you are using Excel as in [your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/437050/group-a-number-of-excel-columns-into-rows), which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @iglvzx I am using the excel 07

Comment: @iglvzx i am needed to use SAS EG or Excel

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VI as text editor, you can easily do

```
:%s/ /\r/g
```

If you are willing to use sed, you can from the commandline in Linux type

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here: It is excel, and the number of rows is small.

There are two steps here:

1. Combine the rows into a single row (just put row 2 after the end of row 1, etc).
2. Select all of row 2, and copy it. Right click in an unoccupied area, and select transpose (or paste special->transpose). Move it where-ever you want.

**Note:** the copy and paste areas for the transpose cannot overlap.